# Initialize array of class objects in constructor of another class

Tags: c++, arrays, data-structures

If I have a class:

```
class A
{
private:
     char z;
     int x;

public:
     A(char inputz, int inputx);
     ~A() {}
}
```

I want to make an array of `A` in class `B`.

```
class B
{
private:
    A arrayofa[26];

public:
    B();
    ~B() {}
    void updatearray(); // This will fill the array with what is needed.
}


class B
{
    B:B()
    {
        updatearray();
        std::sort( &arrayofa[0], &arrayofa[26], A::descend );
    }
}
```

How do I explicitly initialize `arrayofa` in the constructor of `B`?

Comment: Building objects in a constructor is often a bad idea.  What exactly is your goal?

Comment: What is `A::descend`? The normal way to sort things in descending order is to define the normal comparison operators for the class, and then use `std::greater`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default constructor will be called automatically (for non-POD). If you need a different constructor you're out of luck, but you can use `vector` instead which will support what you need.

Answer (score 3):

You can't.

Each element in the array will be initialized by the default constructor (no parameter constructor).

The best alternative is to use a vector.
Here you specify an a value that will be copy constructed into all members of the vector:

```
class B
{
private:
     std::vector<A> arrayofa;
public:
     B()
        : arrayofa(26, A(5,5))
          // create a vector of 26 elements.
          // Each element will be initialized using the copy constructor
          // and the value A(5,5) will be passed as the parameter.
     {}
     ~B(){}
     void updatearray();//This will fill the array with what is needed
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First there should be a default constructor for `class A`, else `B()` will not compile. It will try to call the default constructor of members of `class B` before the body of the constructor starts executing.

You can initialize `arrayofa` like this:

```
void B::updatearray()
{
    arrayofa[0] = A('A', 10);
    arrayofa[1] = A('B', 20);
    ...
}
```

It would be better to use `std::vector` instead of array.

```
std::vector<A> v(26, A('a', 10)); //initialize all 26 objects with 'a' and 10
```